# sharedpreferences is not saving or loading my data Android

Tags: android, android-sharedpreferences

Here is my savaData and loadData method which is used to save and load data

```
 public void saveData(){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences= getActivity().getSharedPreferences("SubjectTitle", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sharedPreferences.edit();
        int i=0,n;
        n=addArray.size();
        for(Bunk b: addArray) {
            editor.putString("Title"+i, b.getTitle());
            editor.putInt("No_of_bunk"+i, b.getBunk_remain());
            editor.putFloat("pre_of_att"+i, b.getPrecentageAtt());
            i++;
        }
        editor.putInt("size_of_data",n);
        editor.apply();
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"data saved",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
    public ArrayList<Bunk> loadData(){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences= getActivity().getSharedPreferences("SubjectTitle", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        int n=sharedPreferences.getInt("size_pf_data",Default);
        String loadTitle;
        int loadBunk;
        float loadAtt;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            loadTitle=sharedPreferences.getString("Title"+i,DEFAULT);
            loadBunk=sharedPreferences.getInt("No_of_bunk"+i,Default);
            loadAtt=sharedPreferences.getFloat("pre_of_att"+i,def_ault);
            addArray.add(new Bunk(loadTitle,loadBunk,loadAtt));
        }
      return addArray;
    }
```

here is code which is used to load data from loadData method

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup perent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreateView(inflater, perent, savedInstanceState);
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, perent, false);
        show=(ListView)v.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    addArray=loadData();
    adapter=new BunkAdapter(addArray);
    show.setAdapter(adapter);
    return v;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You can take the [tour] first and learn [ask] a good question and create a [mcve].  That makes it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 1):

First, use **editor.commit();** to save data after puting them, or directly: `editor.putString("Title"+i, b.getTitle()).commit();` 
Secondly, I believe you're thinking wrong, Shared Preferences is better for things like settings or small amounts of data, in your case, you should use SQLite to save large data.